# Find the exact value of $A(\beta)=8\pi-16\sin(2\beta)$ with $\tan(\beta)= \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> The picture below represents a semi-circumference of diameter [AB] and
>   center C. Point D belongs to the semi-circumference and it's one of
>   the vertices of the triangle $ABC$. Consider that BÂD = $\beta (\beta
>  \in ]0,\frac{\pi}{2}[)$ and AC = 4.
>
> [image]
>
> The area of the pink part of the picture is given by $$A(\beta) =
>  8\pi-16\sin(2\beta)$$
>
> Find the exact value of the area of the pink part with $\tan(\beta)=
>  \frac{1}{2}$

I tried:

$$\tan \beta = \frac{\sin(\beta)}{\cos(\beta)} = \frac{1}{2}\\ \Leftrightarrow \sin(\beta) = \frac{\cos(\beta)}{2} \\ \Leftrightarrow  \sin(\beta) = \frac{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\beta}}{2}\\ \Leftrightarrow ???$$

What do I do next?

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution

Comment: You can square on both sides and continue, taking the positive value for $sin \beta$ as $0 \lt \beta \lt \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: BTW, was the formula for the area given in the question? If so, do you know how to derive it? It's a simple exercise, worth thinking about, if it's not immediately obvious to you.

Comment: @Deepak Not exactly. My book in its quest for dumbed down education gives me the picture, the formula and in the first question it asks me to show that the given formula is correct (in other words, it asks me to derive it anyways). This is so that if a student gets the formula wrong at least they'll get the following exercises correct.

Comment: @Deepak and yes, I do know how to derive it.

Comment: @MarkRead That's good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sin 2\beta = 2\sin \beta \cos \beta$ and $1 + \tan^2 \beta = \frac{1}{\cos^2 \beta}$ so $\cos^2 \beta = \frac{4}{5}$. Also $\sin^2 \beta + \cos^2 \beta = 1$ so $\sin^2 \beta = \frac{1}{5}$ (alternatively you know $\sin \beta = \frac{1}{2}\cos \beta$ from what you've shown).

Hence $\sin 2\beta = 2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{5}}\sqrt{\frac{4}{5}} = \frac{4}{5}$ where we justify the positive root by the fact that $\beta$ is acute.

---

Alternatively, you can draw a right angles triangle with $\beta$ labelled and opposite and adjacent with length $1$ and $2$ so the hypotenuse is $\sqrt{5}$. Then basic trigonometry gives $\sin \beta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ and $\cos \beta = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$

Comment: Could you explain that better? How did you get the values for the sides of that triangle you sugested?

Comment: @MarkRead, we draw a right angled triangle. We label one of the non-90-degree angles by $\beta$. Then we know that $\tan \beta = \frac{1}{2}$ or that opposite/adjacent = 1/2. So we choose a side length for opposite, say 1 for simplicity. Then it follows that the adjacent must be 2 for their ratio to be 1/2. Then we can calculate the hypotenuse as square root of sum of squares. 

We needn't have picked one. We could have chosen the opposite to be a sidelength of $4$, say. Then the adjacent should be $8$. So the hypotenuse is then $\sqrt{80}$. (cont...)

Comment: (...cont) but we still have $\sin \beta = \frac{4}{\sqrt{80}} = \frac{4}{4\sqrt{5}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ nonetheless. All that matters is the ratio of the sides which is specified by $\tan \beta = 1/2$

Comment: I understand now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Given: $\tan \beta = \frac 12$, so $2\sin\beta = \cos \beta$

$\sin 2\beta = 2\sin\beta\cos\beta = \cos^2\beta = \frac 1{\sec^2 \beta} = \frac 1{1 + \tan^2 \beta} = \frac 1{ 1 + \frac 14} = \frac 45$

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan^2\beta=\frac14=\frac{1-\cos^2\beta}{\cos^2\beta}=\frac1{\cos^2\beta}-1$$ so that

$$\cos^2\beta=\frac45,\\\sin^2\beta=\frac15.$$

Then

$$\sin2\beta=2\sin\beta\cos\beta=\pm\frac45.$$

The rest is yours.

Answer (score 1):

look at the right triangle of unit area with sides $1, 2$ and $\sqrt 5.$ the triangle you have is this triangle magnified by $\frac 8{\sqrt 5},$ and therefore has area $\frac{64}5.$ area of the semi circle of radius $4$ is $8\pi$ the area in the question is $$ 8\pi - \frac{64}5.$$

Comment: Could you explain that better? How did you get the values for the sides of that triangle you sugested?

Comment: @MarkRead,  i am using the fact that if you stretch the dimension of a closed region by $k$, then the  area is magnified by $k^2.$

Comment: I see. Why is the area $k^2$ though? What is the logic behind the property in your comment above?

Comment: @MarkRead,  any concept of area has within it that if you scale both "length and width" by a factor of $k$, then the area is scaled by $k^2$. i will guess that the name square itself originates with it.

Comment: I understand that, but could you explain to me why that works?